# Elasticsearch Query - how to?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the data in the following format in Elastic Search  (from sense)

```
POST slots/slot/1
{
    locationid:"1",
    roomid:"10",   
    starttime: "08:45"   
}

POST slots/slot/2
{
    locationid:"1",
    roomid:"10",   
    starttime: "09:00" 
}  


POST slots/slot/3
{
    locationid:"2",
    roomid:"100",   
    starttime: "08:45"   
}  


POST slots/slot/4
{
    locationid:"2",
    roomid:"101",   
    starttime: "09:00"   
}

POST slots/slot/5
{
    locationid:"3",
    roomid:"200",   
    starttime: "09:30"   
}
```

In short , the data is in the following format.

A Location has multiple rooms and each room has multiple slots of 15 minutes. So slot 1 for Room10  starts at 8:45 and ends at 09:00, Slot 2 for same room starts at 09:00 and ends at 09:15

```
Locationid   RoomId    Starttime
--------------------------------------
    1     10        08:45
    1     10        09:00
    2     100       08:45
    2     101       09:00
    3     200       09:30
```

Im trying to write a query/filter which will give me all locations where a room is available with two or three slots.

For e.g Find a location that has 08:45 slot and 09:00 slot (configurable)
 Answer should be location 1 only
Should Not be location 2 as room 100 has 08:45 slot but not the 09:00 slot. Room 101 has 09:00 slot but doesnt have the 08:45 slot

Comment: Any help or is the below answer from me the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not the best approach , but my attempt for the answer

```
POST slots/slot/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count
{
"facets": {
   "locationswithslots": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "locationid",
            "script" : "term + \"_\" + _source.roomid",
         "size": 10
      },

   "facet_filter":
   {         
            "terms": 
            {
               "starttime": 
               [
                  "08:45",
                  "09:00"
               ]
            }


   }
   }
}
```

}

This gives the answer as below

```
{
"took": 12,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 5,
  "max_score": 0,
  "hits": []
 },
 "facets": {
  "locationswithslots": {
     "_type": "terms",
     "missing": 0,
     "total": 4,
     "other": 0,
     "terms": [
        {
           "term": "1_10",
           "count": 2
        },
        {
           "term": "2_101",
           "count": 1
        },
        {
           "term": "2_100",
           "count": 1
        }
     ]
   }
}
}
```

Now I need to figure out a way to filter the facets that return count 2 as I passed in 2 slots in the filter.

Any other option possible?